# React Native - Axios - Google Identity Refresh Token 401 error

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, axios, expo, google-identity-toolkit

I'm using custom tokens and firebase auth. I'm successfully logging in users with email & password and storing the accessToken and refresh tokens. When I go to use the refresh token to get a new access token I'm getting a 401 error. When I try the same post link I'm using in a chrome extension based plugin (for testing REST API's) - the request is successful and I get the desired response. Though with my code in expo & react native I get just a plain, unhelpful 401 error.

My code is as follows:

```
const headers = {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    }
    const data ={
      grant_type : "refresh_token",
      refresh_token : refreshToken

    }
    await axios.post(urlTest, data, {
      headers: headers
    })
    .then((response) => {
     console.log("Success! ", response)
    })
    .catch((error : Error) => {
     console.error(error.name, error.message);
    })
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Maybe a cors issue? A fresh pair of eyes would be welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems it might have been a CORS issue. Changed where I was hosting the code to handle posting and getting new access token. Works a treat now.